# Installing Tensorflow takes too long

Tags: linux, tensorflow, pip

I am trying to install Tensorflow on Linux using `pip`. Each time, the installation gets stuck here:

```
$ pip install tensorflow 

Collecting tensorflow

Using cached tensorflow-1.1.0-cp27-cp27mu-manylinux1_x86_64.whl

Collecting mock>=2.0.0 (from tensorflow)
```

I wait for hours but there is no progress after this step.

Comment: Maybe [try an alternative way to install it](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_linux)?

Comment: I tried with virtualenv it stucks here:                                           

Installing setuptools, pkg_resources, pip, wheel...

Comment: Did you try with `sudo`?

Comment: I am afraid that i don't have sudo access, but it's not needed.People managed to do it without sudo, something is wrong with my account and i am trying to figure out what.

Comment: This issue might be because of broken packages or dependencies. Issue is fixed in latest version of Tensorflow V2.5/2.6 and will install quickly. Use `pip install tensorflow` . Thanks

Comment: I tried to install GPU enabled tensorflow creating conda environment using **conda install -c anaconda tensorflow-gpu**
it stuck at **Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: |/**
any help would be appreciated.